# How does Java handle alpha channel?

Tags: java, encoding, argb

My understanding is that an RGB value with alpha value example could be this `0xffhexcode`.

However, what I cannot understand is how `0xff0000ff`, a solid blue with max alpha value, is an integer value greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. How does the underline encoding in Java allow this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question which boils down to the definition of integer literals.  For a full reference see the language specs at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1

The crux of the matter is that for an integer literal expressed in decimals, you can only represent positive integers. With a hex literal you can express positive and negative values.  And specifically the value will be negative if the first bit is on.

To quote the language specs:

> A decimal numeral is either the single ASCII digit 0, representing the
>   integer zero, or consists of an ASCII digit from 1 to 9 optionally
>   followed by one or more ASCII digits from 0 to 9 interspersed with
>   underscores, representing a positive integer.
>
> A hexadecimal numeral consists of the leading ASCII characters 0x or
>   0X followed by one or more ASCII hexadecimal digits interspersed with
>   underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

So to be precise 0xffffffff is not actually greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE because it is negative (due to the leading bit being on).  Too add to the things that don't look right at first glance you can try:

```
    System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE == 0x7fffffff);
    System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE == 0x80000000);
```

Which will output true for both lines.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the range for pixel is double the max value of Integer, because integer is signed and pixels are unsigned integer. So some colors have negative integer value. eg. white = -1

Answer (score 1):

`int` and `Integer` is signed, the hexadecimal notation you used is unsigned.

EG try something like this:

```
System.out.printf( "%x%n",  -1 );
```

Will output:

> ffffffff